# BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am following a [GEDI tutorial](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/resources/e-learning/getting-started-gedi-l2b-data-python/) on how to work with the Canopy Cover and Vertical Profile Metrics data. Here is the code I am using:

```
path1 = hv.Path(pavdAll, vdims='PAVD').options(color='PAVD', clim=(0,0.13), cmap='Greens', line_width=20, colorbar=True,
                                               width=700, height=550, clabel='PAVD', xlabel='Shot Number', tools=['hover'],
                                               ylabel='Elevation (m)', fontsize={'title':16, 'xlabel':16, 'ylabel': 16,
                                                                                 'xticks':12, 'yticks':12,
                                                                                 'clabel':12, 'cticks':10})
path1
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

> BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length. Current lengths: ('PAVD', 0), ('color', 16), ('xs', 16), ('ys', 16)

I don't know much about programming and would greatly appreciate possible solutions to this error.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liqhY.png)

Comment: Please post your code into a code box. What is the image for? Is this the entirety of your code for this tutorial? I would contact the tutorial creator if you have followed it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out what the problem exactly is, but it seems there now occurs an error when using the HoverTool with hv.Path: https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/4862

Remove `tools=['hover']` from your code and your visualization should work, however without the 'Hovertool' enabled.